# Rails, before_create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Im rails beginner and I tried to add an carrierwave upload for image urls like shown in the episode #253 from railscast. So far all works good when i insert an normal link, for example

```
http:/.....g/dog-01.jpg
```

My problem is that I want to retrieve my images from a javascript plugin that gives a data:image out, how you can see here:

```
var url = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
document.getElementById("canvascontent").value = url;
```

Also you can see that I insert the data:image to an input(#canvascontent).

```
<%= ff.text_field :remote_name_url, class => "canvascontent" %>
```

So now my problem, is that when I try to save simply the data:image from the text_field `:remote_name_url`, this dont works because it is encoded with base64.

The good thing is that Ruby has a Base64 encoder. To encode the data:image and save it in an image file (here png) I wrote a simply code, that I can execute from my console:

```
require 'base64'

data_url = "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAB....."
png      = Base64.decode64(data_url['data:image/png;base64,'.length .. -1])
File.open('testal', 'wb') { |f| f.write(png) }
```

So to come to the end. My problem is that I don't know how to achieve this with rails!
I know that there is an "code" for the model before_create, i tried something like that, but I didn't worked. I think because i have to safe the image first temporally!

```
before_create do
require 'base64'
self.remote_name_url = Base64.decode64(remote_name_url['data:image/png;base64,'.length .. -1])
end
```

```
    class Painting < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :treatment
    attr_accessible :name, :image, :remote_name_url
    mount_uploader :name, BildUploader

    before_create do
require 'base64'
self.remote_name_url =   Base64.decode64(remote_name_url['data:image/png;base64,'.length .. -1])
    end 
    end
```

<

```
 class TreatmentsController < ApplicationController
def create
    @patient = Patient.find(params[:patient_id])
    @treatment = @patient.treatments.create(params[:treatment])
    redirect_to patient_path(@patient)
end
def destroy
    @patient = Patient.find(params[:patient_id])
    @treatment = @patient.treatments.find(params[:id])
    @treatment.destroy
    redirect_to patient_path(@patient)  
end
```

end

Comment: Please add the controller and the model code.

Answer (score 0):

This article from the Carrierwave wiki seems promising:

https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/wiki/How-to%3A-Upload-from-a-string-in-Rails-3

There's also the older technique of using [`Rack::Test::UploadedFile`](http://rdoc.info/github/brynary/rack-test/master/Rack/Test/UploadedFile) and a `StringIO` object, but that looks weirder in code that's not intended for the test environment.